# Redirect to URL - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this function where it checks which divice you are on. What I want now it that it will redirect to a page if the `if` statement is `true` I know how to return a message but I don't know how to redirect instant when `if` statement is true. for example `if($android){` it needs to redirect to google.com

**I want it to redirect to https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bezorgland/id1364919752?mt=8 but that isnt working I get an error then**

```
function user_agent(){
        $iPod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
        $iPhone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
        $iPad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
        $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");

        if($iPad||$iPhone||$iPod){
            return 'ios';
        }else if($android){
            return 'android';
        }else{
            return 'pc';
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: `header("Location: https://google.com"); die();`

Comment: @jonas3344 how to redirect to google.com if `if($android){` is true

Comment: The answer has been given. :)

Comment: As @AniketSahrawat says. But before `ANY` output, even `<HTML>`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I get the error: Warning: Cannot modify header information- headers already sent by (output started at..)

Comment: Honestly, I wonder how you managed to clearly know about Google, yet didn't think about using it.. _"How to redirect with PHP"_ and you would get the first result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/6099347

Comment: well my link doesnt work when I do that @icecub

Comment: "it doesn't work" won't get us anywhere in helping you. How doesn't it work? Does it say the website doesn't exist? Does it tell you the website is only available in the App Store on iOS? Does it not redirect at all? Does it tell you that headers are already sent? Be specific about the problems you're encountering so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function user_agent(){
    $iPod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
    $iPhone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $iPad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");

    function redirect($url){
      if (!headers_sent()){    
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
      } else {  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>'; exit;
      }
   }

   if($iPad||$iPhone||$iPod){
      $url = "http://yoururl.com/ios";
      redirect($url);
   } elseif($android){
      $url = "http://yoururl.com/android";
      redirect($url);
   } else {
      $url = "http://yoururl.com/pc";
      redirect($url);
   }

}
```